Tense of the final verb in counterfactuals
Suppose a speaker is not found out by his girlfriend in the past. He believes that if he got found out by her then he would be killed. There are many ways for him to say that:

彼女に見つかっていたら、殺されるだろう。

彼女に見つかっていたら、殺されただろう。

彼女に見つかっていたら、殺されているだろう。

彼女に見つかっていたら、殺されていただろう。


What are the differences between all 4? I think they differ on observation point of consequent.

The observation point is at the moment before he got killed.

The observation point is the moment after he got killed.

The observation point is now.

The observation point is somewhere between the moment after he got killed and now.



Is there are reason why you're using 見つかっていたら instead of just 見つかったら?

I think it would be helpful if you first wrote out these sorts of differences in an English version for each of your four scenarios.  You seem to be trying to squeeze out differences that seem odd:  for example, in your point #2, how could the speaker speak if he's already been killed?

@A.Ellett All four are counterfactuals. 2 means "if I had found out by her then I would be killed."

In English these might be counterfactuals.  In Indo-European languages, it's easy to clearly state a counterfactual, in English we use the subjunctive.  However, in Japanese, there is no such verbal form which is unambiguously counterfactual.  I feel you're trying to split a hair that's challenging to express in Japanese.  Given a context, you can state a counterfactual quite clearly.  But a standalone sentence in Japanese isn't going to be obviously counterfactual.

@A.Ellett Sorry I don't see what are you trying to say? I didn't list standalone sentences. I supplied some context in the beginning of the post. Is that not enough?

I think your understanding is correct but I also think the same differences apply to non-counterfactual, simple suppositions of fact.
